# Wordpress How Can I Display skill1_logo in View

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi Im practically a newbie and would like to kindly ask how can I display skill1_logo,skill1_title,skill1_description on a page that I want. I was trying to do a 1 page website using wordpress to practice my wordpress.

```
    function theme_skills_customizer($wp_customize){
     //adding section in wordpress customizer
    $wp_customize->add_section('skills_settings_section', array(
      'title'          => 'Skills Section'
     ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('skill1_logo');
    $wp_customize->add_setting('skill1_title');
    $wp_customize->add_setting('skill1_description');
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'skill1_logo', array(
         'label'    => __( 'Skill 1 Logo', 'themeslug' ),
         'width'              => 400,
         'height'             => 400,
         'flex-width'         => true,
         'flex-height'        => true,
         'section'  => 'skills_settings_section',
         'settings' => 'skill1_logo',
    )));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'skill1_title', array(
      'label' => __( 'Skill 1 Title' ),
      'section' => 'skills_settings_section', // Add a default or your own section
      'type' => 'text',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'skill1_description', array(
      'label' => __( 'Skill 1 Description' ),
      'section' => 'skills_settings_section', // Add a default or your own section
      'type' => 'textarea',
    ));

   }

    add_action( 'customize_register', 'theme_skills_customizer' );
```

Comment: it doesn't work on my end.

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_theme_mod` function to echo those settings.

e.g.

```
 $s_title = get_theme_mod('skill1_title');
```

Comment: @RalphySantos sorry my bad, i used wrong function, please check the updated answer, it is get_theme_mod function for customizer settings. Get_option is mostly for plugin level settings..

Comment: Is it the same with images?